# Python - How to solve linear matrix equation AP + PA^T = Q for P (Q, A known)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Suppose I have three matrices A, P, and Q, where only Q and A are known. How can I solve for P using numpy/scipy?

Comment: I think this is a math question not actually a programming question.

Comment: I wanted to know what Python library can easily solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like the continuous [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).  You can use the function [`scipy.linalg.solve_continuous_lyapunov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_continuous_lyapunov.html).